# Subversion merge: nothing is done --accept not taken into account

Tags: svn, merge

I'm trying to merge from branch rep1 into branch rep2
The working directory has been updated to the latest revision of rep2

I issue the command
svn merge --accept=theirs-full $svnurl/rep1 $svnurl/rep2

I get the following output:
--- Merging differences between repository URLs into '.':
   C a
   C c
   C b
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 3

The action I specified to solve conflicts is not applied.

If I remove the --accept option, I get the same output, I'm not asked interactively
how I want to solve the conflict, (i.e. with choices like 'theirs-full','theirs-conflict') ...

I already looked for an answer to this problem, but has not found anythin.

Subversion version is v1.6.17
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

1. Never, **never**, **NEVER!!!** use 2-URL merge without understanding "why", "for that", "how"
2. Read and understand at least `svn help merge`
3. Reply *correct* merge `svn merge --accept "theirs-full" $svnurl/rep1`, maybe with `--dry-run` for testing

BTW, `theirs-full` is terrible idea in common case, but noobs prefer the pain and humiliation.

Comment: Very lazy answer, not constructive and not at all helpful.
Got here because I am having a similar problem, not on 2-URL merge but from 1-URL to current dir, same results, have read the manual, need to understand why this is not working.